# Is it possible to specify a custom width for CSS media rules to use in order to force a desktop mode?

Tags: html, css, browser, media-queries, meta-tags

I want to give my mobile users a desktop mode, but I'm really not interested in making a non-responsive CSS version for every css file i have, so i wonder if it is possible without.

I've googled a bit, and the only suggestion I've seen is setting a custom width in the viewport meta tag. But the css media rules wont listen.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000">
    <!-- CSS -->
  </head>
  <body style="width:1000px;">
    <div class="responsive">
      <p>Why does the CSS media rule still take effect even though I've specified a width in the viewport meta tag?</p>
      <p>I've misunderstood them i bet!</p>
      <p>How can i force it to think its being viewed in another resolution?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="indicator"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.responsive {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  color:black; 
}

@media (max-width: 500px) { 
  .responsive { 
    background: green; 
    color:white; 
  }
}

.indicator { position:fixed; top:0; right:500px; height:100%; width:1px; border-right:2px dashed red; padding:0; }
```

**Live Example**

http://liveweave.com/jB0OfH

**Update**

It actually does work (Just not on desktop - only on mobile). It sets the resolution of the viewport window, which i guess is equivalent of resizing the browser it self on PC.

So you basically can't use use the viewport for anything on PC, and the responsive options i'm making won't work. Would still love a workaround for this that works doesn't involve i frames.

Comment: I would have tried setting the width style on the html element rather than the body element. But apparently it doesn't matter; the viewport (as set in the meta statement) is not the same as the window (as referenced in the media query). I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: By the way, you seem to be saying that "desktop CSS" is the same as "non-responsive". But if you really think like that, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @MrLister Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: "Responsive" means that the page adapts to different screen sizes, not that it can be used on portable and non-portable devices! So for example, if you find that the design looks good on a 1920px wide screen, but you need to change the layout on a 1366px screen to look good too, that is responsive design as well. No matter the type of hardware.

Comment: @MrLister Ah, just wanted to make sure. - I'm not thinking of it wrong then. I just explained the problem from my users point of view... Perhaps not the right thing to do on stackoverflow :p

Comment: I was thinking about `@viewport` But I checked the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport) - guess better not use it.

Comment: @StefanKunze Perhaps it only works for mobile devices, and desktop browsers just completely ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good solution so I won't mark it as correct, but it is a solution...

Wrap the entire page in an `iframe` that has `width:100%` and `min-width:1000px`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      iframe, body, html {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding:0;
        border:none;
        min-width:1000px; 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="linkToPage"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider putting a `.responsive` class on the body element, then write your CSS as

```js
function toggle() {
   document.body.classList.toggle("responsive");
 }
```

```css
.class {
   padding: 20px;
   background: orange;
   color: black; 
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
    
 @media (max-width: 500px) { 
   body.responsive .class { 
     background: green; 
     color: white; 
   }
 }
```

```html
<body class="responsive">
  <div id="box" class="class"></div>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle responsive</button>
</body>
```

With the `.responsive` class on the body, the media query will kick in. Without the `.responsive` class on the body, it will be ignored.